# Easiest way to print the updated array? to display 'S'?

Tags: java, arrays

What would be the simplest way of printing the updated grid after the user has input x and y co-ords this system is for placing battleships on a grid.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TheGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            System.out.println("Players Board");

            char[][] grid = new char[10][10];
            //FILL GRID//
            for (int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue < 10; outerLoopValue++) {
                for (int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue < 10; innerLoopValue++) {
                    grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue] = 'O';
                }
            }
            //END OF FILL GRID//
            //DRAW GRID//
            for (int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue < 10; outerLoopValue++) {
                System.out.println("");
                for (int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue < 10; innerLoopValue++) {
                    System.out.print(grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue] + "  ");
                }
            }
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Please Choose the Co-ordinates of your first ship");
            System.out.println("X = ");
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Y = ");
            int y = sc.nextInt();

            grid[x][y] = 'S';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the same loop you used for drawing grid

Comment: would there not be a way to condense this and give it a command to call such as PrintGrid() sort of thing ofc i have no idea how to do this

Comment: Use the same loop under the comment  //DRAW GRID//

Comment: @Chop that will be good approach

Comment: Just to itterate, i will be needing 3 diff grids also one for player one for cpu one for shots fired so this method would not work in the full program if im not wrong.

Comment: @osama inayat what would this method be called could i find a tutorial on it?

Comment: make a new method named drawGrid(char[][]){ // your loop} simply call this again to achieve what what you want

Comment: create a function and pass the array as a parameter.

Comment: @chop i can provide you with the code also but this may hurt self learning

Comment: @Osama Inayat coding is just part of my overall Games design course, i am not really interested in programming and learning it as per say but have to pass the unit. If i had more time on my assignment i would go back to the beginning as i have gaps in my knowledge if you could provide me with the code id be grateful if its not too much hassle

Comment: @Chop kindly check answers if any query tell me there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public static void drawGrid(char[][]){
             for(int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue<10;outerLoopValue++)
             {
                System.out.println("");
                for(int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue<10;innerLoopValue++)
                 {
                   System.out.print(grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue]+"  ");
                 }

            }

}
```

**SO WHAT WILL BE YOUR FINAL CODE**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TheGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {

            System.out.println("Players Board");

            char[][] grid = new char[10][10];
//FILL GRID//
            for (int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue < 10; outerLoopValue++) {

                for (int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue < 10; innerLoopValue++) {
                    grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue] = 'O';
                }

            }
            //END OF FILL GRID//
            //DRAW GRID//
            drawGrid(grid);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Please Choose the Co-ordinates of your first ship");
            System.out.println("X = ");
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Y = ");
            int y = sc.nextInt();

            grid[x][y] = 'S';
            drawGrid(grid);

        }

    }


    //i am making a static method so it will be easy for 
    // you to call it from static method
    //Main method is static
    //else if you dont want it to be static than you have to
    //make object to the class to call this method
    //considering your beginner level i m making
    //this method static
    //Your question..
    /*
    why is there two public static void?
    */
    //The Answer is this we want to reuse the same code
    //public static void in most simple way 
    //you may call this as syntax[considering basic level]
    //void is class from java.lang 
    //if you keep on doing the same code in the
    //same method than you cannt reuse anything
    //and have to write same code again and again
    //for the same process
     public static void drawGrid(char[][] grid){
             for(int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue<10;outerLoopValue++)
             {
                System.out.println("");
                for(int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue<10;innerLoopValue++)
                 {
                   System.out.print(grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue]+"  ");
                 }

            }

}
}
```

I think It is what how you want if any problem kindly comment i will correct i have not checked this

Comment: ahhh im so stressed thanks for trying to help, why is there two public static void? i thought i can only have one of these. So the code you have given me will fit somewhere in my originial code?

Comment: wait let me give it an edit to make it easy to understand

Comment: thankyou so much, i really am a noob at java so i need super simple terms.

Comment: @Chop i have edited the code any further query you may ask

Comment: im sorry i really dont understand this whether i put the public static void drawgrid part in another class or in the same class its always an error that whats confusing me. Also what do you mean by a method and static. Does void mean return nothing back?

Comment: Thankyou this is now working, so now if i want another grid do i just use the command drawgrid? if i want a grid for cpu and for shots how will i make sure im printing a different grid for these? make another method the same as yours and make it drawgrid1 for example?

Comment: drawGrid(grid); is method call

Comment: if you want to draw another grid just pass the grid to the method

Comment: as in  this example the array name was grid so i pass that to drawGrid

Comment: @ yes i see this, so what i am saying is i need a different grid for the Computer ai to place his ships on, do i need to create a new method with a different name such as drawgrid2?  i need to be able to alternate between these grids, when i do this it just gives me the same as drawgrid 2 even though i have made a complete new method.

Comment: no you dont need a different method  just before calling the method give a System.out.println("Thie is Grid for Computer ai"); and pass the array as we pass....  as long as your array is 2D you can use this method

Comment: Sorry i feel i dont even know what I am asking im clueless! i see what you have done so you made: 1. New method which i can call with drawGrid. called the method so that it prints which i completely understand. But now how do i get a new grid i made a new method under the name drawGrid2 but it is giving me the same results what i am doing is probably completely wrong but i really am that clueless about java right now.

Comment: yes but everytime i call the drawgrid it will draw the same one i have been updating, so when the computer places his ships it will always be showing mine?

Comment: no it will  not it will update it where computer placed the ships thats why i recalled the drawGrid again to print the grid so that we may witness it